# Changing Date Display format based on the Selected Time Zone

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timezone

I have list of all time zones in world.My goal is to display the date and time based on the time zone selected by the user or client.

```
 i.e. in the US we list DD/MM/YY. In India they use MM/DD/YY.
```

How do i achieve this?Is there any possibility of changing the date format based on the time zone selected?

Pls provide any suggestions or sample coding to achieve this....

I wanted to know whether date format can be changed based on the Time zone selected?

Comment: Just a side note, isn't it the other way round? The US seem to be the only country using `MM/DD/YY` notation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_notation_by_country

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5700049/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1):

because there is no way on clientside to achive this, my suggestion is select the time zone on clientside, make an ajax request to the server, generate the time zone on server side (if possible) and display it in browser.

Comment: I believe OP is asking about how to "present" the date.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Date.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) method. It will convert the dates into the format determined by end-user's system settings:

```
var d = new Date("20/10/2000");
d.toLocaleDateString();
```

The important thing to note is that the user must have set correct regional settings on his/her computer. Many people do not bother to change them and instead choose the default (en-us) when they install the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the active culture. First option is to change the culture to the one you want and then just print out the date.

```
public static void Set(string culture)
{
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
}
```

Comment: who's just so funny to downvote an acceptable answer without commentating what should be improved?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple times it is helpful to know 'which' format the user computer assigns for date and month formatting.

You can determine this once, and use it to arrange your inputs and sidplay value everywhere-

```
Date.ddmm= (function(){
    return Date.parse('2/6/2009')> Date.parse('6/2/2009');
})(),
```

//returns true if format is dd-mm-yyyy, false otherwise